# 2003 SagePay Error Code

Tags: salesforce, opayo

We are getting the following error message from **SagePay**. I have tried to research the error code but could not find anything relevant.

Can anyone shed some light on what this error is? (We are using **Salesforce with Steelbrick** to take the payment)

**Error:**

[Sage Pay Error Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lTQz.png)

Comment: How can we possibly help without seeing your code or any information on your system at all?

Comment: All the information I have available is in the attached image. Salesforce/Steelbrick is the platform used to interface SagePay, but it is SagePay that is creating the error shown. It is only happening for one transaction and not any of the others. (Mastercard apparently) I do not know what else I can provide unfortnately, was hoping someone has seen the error code before.

Comment: Then you should call SagePay or SalesForce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually an authorization problem (it doesn't manifest itself very well from the Sage Pay side). It may be a problem with your MID - I recommend contacting Sage Pay to get as much information as you can, then contacting your acquiring bank.